# Are prop creation technique related questions welcome here?

Tags: discussion

Creation of theatrical properties, or props, is important to movie making.
Are questions related to them and how to create/maintain/dispose them on-topic here?

Answer (score 4):

The site is about video/audio production, not "movie making" in its entirety. The focus is on the "studio production" side to it, although there are some exceptions where the basic problem domain is the same (live sound, shooting video on location, etc).

I think making props should be off-topic here, unless the question is about how making those props will affect production - for example, a question about how different prop materials will affect lighting would be interesting.

As a comparison on the audio side, we have lots of questions about audio production but we don't discuss musicianship outside of a studio/recording context - we have [another site for that](http://music.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think prop questions are explicitly on topic here (just my 2 cents).  However, the argument can certainly be made that props are a part of video "production", if indeed there is recording happening.

Quoting [an answer](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/a/206/2569) by Atwood, as long as there is,

> at least some semblance of a defensible connection to production

you should probably be safe.

Secondly, [yet another Atwood answer](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/a/92/2569) is, I believe, pertinent...

> The general guideline we use is that experts using the site would not
>   be turned off or turned away by the presence of this particular topic
>   appearing on the site.

Of course none of this definitively answers your question :)  But those two quotes should give you a bit of support if you decide to post your question and get some push-back.  I can't say I wouldn't push back a bit myself though... depends on your question. :)

Comment: Nice finds! For me the second quote is very insightful and reasonable; In particular I've never understood that aspect of SE and now I will keep that in mind as one of my personal how-to-ask guidelines!

Comment: The Atwood comment is interesting, but seems to be contradicted by the masses of 'please do this trivial homework for me' questions that are left alive over on StackOverflow. I'm vastly more experienced in software engineering than AV stuff, but I find the AVP questions much more interesting.